# MATLAB offset when plotting integration of sin

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a question, because this work for many functions, but I have a trouble when trying to plot the integral of a sine (I am using matlab 2010):

```
clear all
close all
clc

x = linspace(-10, 10, 100);

f = @(x) sin(x);

I = arrayfun(@(x) quad(f, 0, x), x);
plot(x, f(x),'r', x, I, 'b')
```

I expect having a -cos(x), but instead I get something with an offset of 1, why is this happening? How should fix this problem?

Comment: You are using `0` as lower integration limit. So the definite integral (`I`) should be `0` at *x* = `0`, which it is. What offset do you find?

Comment: I don't think your code does what you think it does.

Comment: yes, I found my mistake, my lower boundary is just arbitrary. there is no offset and the result is what is expected. However I wanted to, for instance, if I have f(x) = sin(x), plot f(x) and what I get when I integrate f(x) considering the integration constant equal to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) says that the indefinite integral of a [nice function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764354/nice-functions) *f*(*x*) is equal to the function's antiderivative *F*(*x*), which is unique up-to an additive constant.  Further, a definite integral has the form:

[image: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus]

In this form, the constant of integration will cancel out, and the integral will exactly equal the desired antiderivative *only if the lower bound evaluation vanishes*. However, `-cos(0)` does not vanish and has a value of `-1`.  So in order to calculate the desired antiderivative *F*(*x*), the lower bound evaluation should be added to the right-hand side.

```
plot(x, f(x),'r', x, I+ (-cos(0)), 'b');
```

This is the equivalent of assigning an initial value for the solution of ODEs a la `ode45`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do can be achieved using the following:

```
x = linspace(-10, 10, 100);

syms y;
f = sin(y)     %function

I =int(f,y)    %integration of f
plot(x, subs(f,y,x),'r', x, subs(I,y,x), 'b')
```

**Output:-**

[image: output]

Comment: I think you mean `integral`, which is the numerical version of the Symbolic `int`.

Comment: Indeed.  I'll note, however, that `integral` was added in R2012a as the modern integrator.  In the OP's R2010 release, I think `quad` was still the default.

Answer (score 0):

According to Matlab documentation, `q = quad(fun,a,b)`

> Quadrature is a numerical method used to find the area under the graph of a function, that is, to compute a definite integral.

Integral of sin(x) equals -cos(x)

Definite integral of `sin(x)` from `x = pi` to `x = 0`:
`-cos(pi) - (-cos(0)) = 2`

Since `quad` compute a definite integral, I can't see any problem.

Same as:
`figure;plot(-cos(x) - (-cos(0)))`

Comment: yes, you are right, I was testing with numerical examples and the result makes sense. I am doing a homework in where it is asked plotting the integral of a function and the function, but that makes no sense, since the integral depends on the integration interval, so... I guess there was not problem at all, since my lower boundary was arbitrary, in this case 0

Comment: Thank you for refreshing my memory about definite and indefinite integrals.